# In Postgres, can ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT be used to implement "attempts" when using "FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED"?

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions

Postgres 10

I have a table in Postgres in which table rows are work queue items. Worker processes grab a row and do some processing on it.

```
sql = """BEGIN;
UPDATE jobs SET status = 'complete'
WHERE id = (
  SELECT id
  FROM jobs
  WHERE status = 'finished_waiting'
  AND status != 'failed'
  ORDER BY created ASC 
  FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
  LIMIT 1
)
RETURNING *;
"""
```

My existing code is above.  If the processing succeeds, then I issue a "COMMIT", and if fails, "ROLLBACK".

I use the Postgres "FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED" feature to safely grab and process each row, and if processing fails, the row is returned to the table in its original state for reprocessing.

BUT I need to have some sort of "attempts" functionality, so that repeatedly failing task rows do not continue to be processed infinitely.

I was reading about "ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT" and I wondered is there any way it can be used to increment an "attempts" table column in the case in which the processing fails and the transaction is rolled back?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Set a savepoint right after the `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`.

If processing fails, rollback to the savepoint, increment `attempts` and commit.